# Issues with UDP client to UDP server with 10057 error

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, winsockets

I have an issues of connecting to my UDP server. On VS it showed no errors except when I do an error checking it give me a Error 10057.

UDP Client:

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define ZeroMemory

using namespace std;

WSADATA wsadata;
SOCKET  Client;
SOCKADDR_IN Server;
unsigned int Port = 5020;
int ret;
char buf[4096];
int len, tolen, fromlen, namelen;


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // Initialize Winsocket
    ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadata);
                // CHECKS THE SOCKET STATUS
                if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    printf("Client: Winstock Status is: %s ", wsadata.szSystemStatus);
                    WSACleanup();
                    cout << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Client: Winstock Status is: %s ", wsadata.szSystemStatus);
                    cout << endl;
                }

                // Client Address
                Server.sin_family = AF_INET;
                Server.sin_port = htons(Port);
                inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &Server.sin_addr);

    // Create Socket
    ret = Client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    // CHECKS IF SOCKET IS CREATED
                if (Client == INVALID_SOCKET)
                {
                    cout << "Client: Can't Create Socket! ERROR: %s " << WSAGetLastError();
                    WSACleanup();
                    cout << endl;
                }

    // Bind Socket
    ret = bind(Client, (sockaddr*)& Server,sizeof(Server));

                // CHECKS IF SOCKET IS BINDED
                if (ret == INVALID_SOCKET)
                {
                    cout << "Client: Failed to bind socket" << WSAGetLastError(); ;
                    cout << endl;
                }

                string s(argv[1]);


                    // SendTo()
                    ret = sendto
                    (
                        Client,
                        s.c_str(),
                        s.size() + 1,
                        0,
                        (sockaddr*) & Server,
                        sizeof(Server)
                    );

                    if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR);
                    {
                        cout << "That did not work! Error Code: " << WSAGetLastError();
                        cout << endl;
                    }


    // CloseSocket
    closesocket(Client);

    // CleanUp Winsocket
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

UDP Server:

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

WSADATA wsadata;
SOCKET  ServerSocket;
SOCKADDR_IN ServerAddress, Client;
unsigned int Port = 5020;
char buf[4096];
int ret;
int len, tolen, fromlen, namelen;

int main()
{

    // Initializing Socket
    ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadata);
        if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "Server: Failed to initialized socket. Error: " << wsadata.szSystemStatus;
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Server: Successfully initialized socket." << wsadata.szSystemStatus;
            cout << endl;
        }

    // Sever Address
    ServerAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddress.sin_port = htons(Port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &ServerAddress.sin_addr);

    // Create Socket
    ret = ServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        cout << "Server: Failed to create socket. Error: " << WSAGetLastError();
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Server: Socket has been created ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    // Bind Socket
    ret = bind(ServerSocket, (sockaddr*)& ServerAddress, sizeof(ServerAddress));
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        cout << "Server: Failed to bind socket. Error: " << WSAGetLastError();
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Server: Socket is binded to address ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    int ClientLength = sizeof(Client);

    while(true)
    {

        // receivefrom
        ret = recvfrom
        (
            ServerSocket,
            buf,
            len,
            0,
            (sockaddr*)& Client,
            &ClientLength
        );

        if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "Error receiving from client" << WSAGetLastError();
        }

        // display message
        char ClientIP[256];

        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &Client.sin_addr, ClientIP, 256);

        cout << "message recieve from: " << ClientIP << " : " << buf << endl;
    }

    // Close Socket
    closesocket(ServerSocket);

    // Cleanup Winsocket
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

I have executed the client first, no issues, executed server then client that's when it showed the issue.

```
// SendTo()
ret = sendto
(
    Client,
    s.c_str(),
    s.size() + 1,
    0,
    (sockaddr*) & Server,
    sizeof(Server)
);

if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR);
{
    cout << "That did not work! Error Code: " << WSAGetLastError();
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: in case anyone doesn't want to bother doing the due-diligence the OP didn't do, 10057 means "socket is not connected". When using `sendto` is typically means no target address was supplied, or if one was supplied, it was bogus.

Comment: Sorry! I including the same link as of the UDP client I edited my question to include my UDP server. UDP Server: http://codepad.org/YVDdZv93

Comment: @WhozCraig lol right, spam removed

Answer (score 3):

Two mistakes:

1. `ret = Client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);`

   If you are writing a UDP client, you need to create a UDP socket, not a TCP socket:

   ```
   ret = Client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
   ```
2. `ret = bind(Client, (sockaddr*)& Server,sizeof(Server));`

   This is on the client side. Why are you trying to `bind()` to the server's endpoint? You use `bind()` to set the *local* address of the socket, not the *remote* address. Use `connect()` for the remote address (which you don't need to do when using `sendto()`).